# pytesseract not detecting numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

[image: What I am trying to read]

The picture I am trying to read is outputting "ones". I don't know how it's getting that. My code:

```
left = 980
right = 1000
top = 237
bottom = 265
CroppedImage = cropimage.crop((left,top,right,bottom))
if os.path.isfile("Price.png"):
        os.remove("Price.png")
CroppedImage.save('Price.png', 'PNG')


Check_Price = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('Price.png'), lang='eng')
Check_Price = Check_Price[:-2]
if len(Check_Price) == 4:
    Found_Price = True
print(Check_Price)
```

I have pytesseract properly installed and PIL. It's all working for 2 other ones that I have, but it just won't read this text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale the image up, using this code i can get your number you need.

```py
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

def read():
    i = Image.open('./JA9JF.png')
    scale = 2.1
    i_width = i.size[1] * scale
    i_height = i.size[0] * scale
    i = i.resize((int(i_width), int(i_height)), Image.BILINEAR)
    xconfig = "-c page_separator=''"
    Check_Price = pytesseract.image_to_string(i, lang='eng', config=xconfig)
    print(Check_Price)

read()
```

And so your code would be.

```py
left = 980
right = 1000
top = 237
bottom = 265
CroppedImage = cropimage.crop((left,top,right,bottom))
if os.path.isfile("Price.png"):
        os.remove("Price.png")
CroppedImage.save('Price.png', 'PNG')

i = Image.open('Price.png')
scale = 2.1
i_width = i.size[1] * scale
i_height = i.size[0] * scale
i = i.resize((int(i_width), int(i_height)), Image.BILINEAR)

xconfig = "-c page_separator=''"
Check_Price = pytesseract.image_to_string(i, lang='eng', config=xconfig)
Check_Price = Check_Price[:-2]
if len(Check_Price) == 4:
    Found_Price = True
print(Check_Price)
```

i've added `xconfig = "-c page_separator=''"` because for me pytesseract add \n\x0c for some reason. I also don't know if this will work with other numbers, if it doesn't I'll have to fix it using cv2.